# Cannot disable Path Hints for Storefront

Tags: magento2, template-hints

I enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront, though magento administration panel. Then, I tried to disable them, but they are stuck in enabled mode.

I have also tried the following:

- `php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable`
- `php bin/magento cache:clean`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Path hints are always enabled.

ps. the setting is disabled in all store views

Comment: Any error warning generate in system.log?

Comment: go to admin backend:

Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following check/tasks to disable the template hints:

1) Go into the database and look for all records in "core_config_data" with the path 'dev/debug/template_hints_storefront'. They should all be set to '0' as value.

2) Remove content from folders:

- /generated/
- /var/
- /pub/static/

3) php bin/magento cache:flush

4) Run site

Comment: I will accept your answer as a solution, cause I did'nt finally foind what was the reason for this. After some time, the problem was solved without me doing anything. I guess that this is one of the many things magento2 drives us to madness.